# A way to exclude self from Bonjour search results

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bonjour

When the same app acts as a Bonjour-enabled service and client at the same time, browsing for self-like services while listening on a socket, what's a good way to exclude self from service search results?

Comment: Have you ever solved that? If so, could you please provide an answer to your own question?

Comment: Solved. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server part, when I register my service with Bonjour, I generate a 10 character random alphanumeric string - a cookie. I make it a part of the advertised service name, as provided in call to `[NSNetService initWithDomain:type:name:port:]`. The resulting name is something like "MyApp on Joe's iPhone\txYbG56HjaE". The part before the tab character is for display, the part after is the cookie. I then store the cookie is a globally visible variable. Since server initialization takes place on app startup, the cookie value is available early on.

In the service discovery part, when I find a service, I check its name; if the cookie is the same as the stored global one, I skip this service. The idea is that other running instances of the program would have different cookie values, because randomness.

Naturally, when displaying discovered service names in the UI, I skip the part after the tab character.

Comment: Not a hash, technically speaking. Just a random string, like a session ID in ASP.

Comment: This seems like a hack. Please consider my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In your NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate you can just ask the incoming service if it is the same as the one you have published:

```
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    if ([netService isEqual:self.publishedNetService])
        return;
    …
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, used it and confirmed it by looking at the disassembly. CFNetServiceRef is implementing a correct isEqual function as expected. I have not found anything about it in the documentation though.